# If we construct a tree of all paths leading out of some root node, is that tree necessarily unique?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

### Introduction

Our goal is to prove whether or not something called a "*path tree*" is unique for any directed graph $G$.

### Informal definition of  *Path Tree*

Pick a digraph, any digraph.

Designate an arbitrary node in the digraph to be a root node.

A ***path tree*** for that digraph is rooted at the same root node.

Also, each node in digraph $G$ appears in the path-tree many times.

Specifically, the exact number of times a node $x$ from digraph $G$ is duplicated in tree $T$ is equal to the number of paths from the root node to node $x$ in graph $G$.

### Formal definition of  *Path Tree*

A *tree* is any directed graph $T$ such that:

- the tree has exactly one root node
- the tree has zero or more branch nodes
- the tree has zero or more leaf nodes.
  A “*root node*” is any node $r$ which has zero incoming edges and one outgoing edge. That is, $\forall r \in VS(T)$, $r$ is a *root node* if and only if $\begin{Bmatrix}V \in VS(T): (V, r) \in AS(T) \end{Bmatrix} = Ø$   and  $\exists X \in \begin{Bmatrix}V \in VS(T): (r, V) \in AS(T) \end{Bmatrix}$ and  $\forall X, Y \in \begin{Bmatrix}V \in VS(T): (r, V) \in AS(T) \end{Bmatrix}$, $X = Y$ .
  It should be obvious what *branch nodes* are.
  We define *leaf nodes* to be any nodes which have exactly one incoming edge and zero outgoing edges.

#### Formal Definition of Path Tree

Let $G$ be a directed graph with vertex set $VS(G)$  and arc-set $AS(G)$.
For example, maybe $VS(G) =\begin{Bmatrix} 1, 2, 3, 4 \end{Bmatrix}$ and $AS(G) =\begin{Bmatrix} (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (4, 4) (3, 2), (3, 3)\end{Bmatrix}$
Note that we allow $G$ to have self-loops $\begin{pmatrix}(x,x)\in AS \end{pmatrix}$
Let $r$ be a node in digraph $G$.

a “*Path Tree*” of digraph $G$ rooted at node $r \in VS(G)$ is defined to be a tree $T$ such that there exists a mapping $\mathcal{toG}$ from the vertex set of tree $T$ to the vertex set of digraph $G$ such that all of the following are true:

- There exists a unique tree-node $r^{\prime}$ such that $\mathcal{toG}(r^{\prime}) = r$
- $\forall V \in VS(T)$, $1 \leq \begin{vmatrix} \begin{Bmatrix} W \in VS(G): \mathcal{toG}(V) = W \end{Bmatrix} \end{vmatrix}$ and $\begin{vmatrix} \begin{Bmatrix} W \in VS(G): \mathcal{toG}(V) = W \end{Bmatrix} \end{vmatrix}$ is equal to the number of distinct paths from $r = \mathcal{toG}(r^{\prime})$ to $\mathcal{toG}(V)$ in directed graph $G$.
  The paths are not necessarily disjoint from other paths, but nodes inside of a path are guaranteed to be distinct from other nodes inside of the same path.

## Re-stating the Question

Is the path-tree associated with rooted-digraph guaranteed to be unique for that choice of root and digraph?

#### Note

What I call a "*path tree*" is like a spanning tree in many ways, except that nodes get repeated.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question as asking how to properly define the path tree that you have in mind. You do not say much about the edges of the path tree, so I have to guess what your intention is.

Given a rooted digraph $G$, just *define* the vertices of its path tree to be the finite paths in $G$ which start at the root, and let there be a directed edge in the path tree from a path $p_0$ in $G$ to a path $p_1$ in $G$ if $p_1$ is obtained from $p_0$ by adding one edge at the end.

This defines a directed graph, and it is easily seen that each vertex can be reached from the vertex corresponding to the path of length $0$ in $G$ by exactly one path, which corresponds to the finite sequence of initial parts of the corresponding path in $G$.